# VNC access to Chromebook?

Tags: remote-desktop, google-chrome-os, chromebook

My grandmother is beginning to use a computer soon. We are giving her a chromebook so that it will be easier to keep the settings right, and not get lost.

However, for support purposes, and helping set up new things like bookmarks, plugins, and so forth, we want to set up remote control of the chromebook. It is not necessary for her to approve each remote control session.

We do have physical access to the machine before we deliver it to her. This will give us an opportunity to make any changes necessary to allow this.

I am a competent software developer, and can work with Linux, but have never worked under the hood of a chromebook before. What would be necessary to accomplish this remote access?

Comment: A [forum conversation](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2BNB4Z34R7k%5B1-25-false%5D) on Google groups seems to have a number of people in your boat, but Google has not released support for it yet, reasoning that Chrome OS is a stateless system and there "is no need for it".

Comment: When trying to Share your own Chrombook with "Chrome Remote Desktop" it says: "This feature is not yet available for Chrombooks... stay tuned". But don't hold your breath. I believe it's that way since 2011 (its initial release).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has recently become possible to do with the [Chrome Remote Desktop App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp).

Brief instructions:

- Install the Chrome Remote Desktop App on the Chromebook and Chrome on your computer.
- On the Chromebook: (You'll have to show your grandmother how to do this.)

  - Launch the app. (I guess the most convenient way would be to Pin it to the Shelf ahead of time.)
  - Under Remote Assistance, click "Get Started". (I think you only need to click this the first time you use the app.)
  - Click the green Share button.
  - (Click "Share" at the prompt.)
  - A 12-digit access code appears.
- On your Chrome browser:

  - Launch the app.
  - Under "Remote Assistance", click "Get Started".
  - Click "Access" next to "See and control a shared computer".
  - (It asks for an access code.)
  - Enter the access code that the Chromebook computer generated.

Comment: this is better than nothing, but it's too bad you can't have an unattended connection. how do I remote to a system that's a half-mile away with no one near it?

Comment: You use Crouton or Crostini?

Comment: The ability to access a Chromebook doesn't seem to exist anymore. i.e. The option for Remote Assistance isn't there anymore.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

2022 update:  The instructions and extension linked here worked for me:  https://remotedesktop.google.com/support/

You'll be presented with 2 options:

1. Share this screen

   - This has button to install extension, or
   - once installed, a button to `+ Generate Code`
2. Connect to another computer

   - Here you enter the 12-digit Access code given to you by the other person

The computer being remote controlled was an ASUS Chromebox, running ChromeOS Flex Beta (will eventually replace [Neverware](https://www.neverware.com/) CloudReady since [Google bought them](https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/article/Neverware-is-now-part-of-Google-FAQ)).  It's based on Chromium v100.  The client was Chrome v99 for macOS.

While it still doesn't answer the OP's original Q, because it would require grandma to click a few things and read the Access Code (over the phone; expires in 5 minutes), and then confirm once you connect, but should be usable.  Although a vast majority of phone-scammers assume you're running Windows or macOS, it may be worth telling grandma to ***never*** do this for some stranger who calls.

Other interesting tidbit: has a "stats for nerds" similar to YouTube, and uses the v8 codec.  Performance was quite good (but I was testing on LAN).

Although I didn't test it, seems like the *Chrome Remote Desktop* extension can also be used for Windows and macOS hosts - it prompts download+install of a `.msi` or `.dmg` file.  The client works directly in the browser without additional install.

Answer (score -1):

Teamviewer works on chromebooks, PC and Mac and works unattended as long as the computer is on. (even if its off you can do WOL in BIOS to network turn on)

Answer (score -1):

Update 2023 Nov, Teamviewer Host for android can be download via google play, and can be utilized to remote control unattended Chromebook, as long as it's open. it's supposed to work even when lid is closed, just set Chromebook as "Do not close monitor when it's charging", please commend if it does not work for you.[Teamviewer for android](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/109610-remote-control-an-android-device-via-unattended-access).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).